# Adding recursively to a set

Tags: python, recursion, set

How can I add recursively to a set, when set itself is unhashable?

```
s = set()
if root.children == []:      
    if str(root.value) not in s:        
        s.add(str(root.value))
        return s
    else:
        if str(root.value) not in s:
            s.add(str(root.value))
        for child in root.children:
            s.add(distinct_leaf_helper(child))
        return s
```

this will result in a TypeError

Comment: Maybe use a `frozenset`?

Comment: do you want to add *all* elements?

Comment: If you want to add all elements, you can write a generator function `traverse()` to traverse the tree `yield` ing each node's value. Then you can do `s = set(traverse())`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to add the children as sets, you can use a `frozenset`:

```
s.add(frozenset(distinct_leaf_helper(child)))
```

though I guess your intention is to add all the elements from the child set, in which case you'd use `.update()` to add the elements of the given iterable into the set:

```
s.update(distinct_leaf_helper(child))
```

Comment: So (root.value)s are mutable to I'm first turning them into strings, I want to add all the nodes that are not already in the set -> unique nodes